# Onsen UI and AngularJS can't access new scope variables from templates

Tags: angularjs, templates, scope, onsen-ui

I'm building a simple ios app with PhoneGap + OnsenUI + AngularJS and a have a problem with the scope variables.
I only have 1 Controller.

So... I have a list with items and when i click one item i execute a function in the controller passing the clicked object.
In the function i assign the object in the scope

```
$scope.newVar = obj
```

For some reason when i execute pushPage from the executed function, in the template file i can't access that new variable but i can access the old ones from the other pages.
In the browsers debugger i can see the new variable in the $scope.

The 2 functions that i have are these:
The first one is from the first page.. and the showSelectedPics is the one i have the problem.

```
  $scope.showSubCatPic = function(pic) {
    $scope.currentSubCat = pic.category; // i can access from the 2nd page template
    $scope.currentCat = pic.subs; // i can access from the 2nd page template
    $scope.currentBasedir = pic.basedir; // i can access from the 2nd page template
    mediaNavigator.pushPage('show-sub-cats-pic.html', {
      animation: "slide-left"
    });
  };

  $scope.showSelectedPics = function(sub) {
    $scope.currentPic = sub; // this is the variable that i can't access
    $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('pictures.html');
  };
```

HTML from the 1st page:

```
<ons-page ng-controller="AppController">
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
        <div class="center">{{currentSubCat}}</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
        <ons-list class="treatment-list">
            <ons-list-item class="person" modifier="chevron" ng-repeat="sub in currentCat" ng-click="showSelectedPics(sub)">
                <ons-row>
                    <ons-col class="treatment-name">
                        {{sub.title}}
                    </ons-col>
                </ons-row>
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
</ons-page>
```

HTML from the page that i have the problem:

```
<ons-page ng-controller="AppController">
    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
        <div class="center">{{currentPic.title}}</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
        <ons-list class="treatment-list">
            <ons-list-item class="person">
                <ons-row>
                    <ons-col class="treatment-name">
                        {{currentPic.title}}
                    </ons-col>
                </ons-row>
            </ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
</ons-page>
```

Is there something wrong with the code???? If not can anyone tell me how can i pass the object to the template file. I don't mind if it's the "wrong way" to do this. I just wanna make this work..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting the `ngController` directive on the `<body>` tag instead. If you do that it would be parent to both the template and the first page so you should be able to use the scope variables in both places.